# Subspaces related problem from hoffman kunze

Tags: linear-algebra

$ W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ are given to be subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $$W_{1}+W_{2}=V \text{ and }W_1 \cap W_2=0$$ We have to prove that for each $\alpha$ in $V$ there are unique vectors $\alpha_{1}\in W_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}  \in W_{2} $ such that $\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2} = \alpha$

And here is what I've tried so far: 
   By a definition given in my textbook (Hoffman and Kunze), elements of the set $W_{1} +W_{2}$ are of the type $\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}$ where $\alpha_{1} \in W_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2} \in W_{2}$.

And since $W_{1} +W_{2}=V$, I further assumed any element $\alpha$ of $V$.

Now the existence part follows automatically from above as $\alpha=\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}$.

**Proof of the uniqueness part:**

To the contrary I assumed for any $\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2} \in W_{1} +W_{2}$ , where $\alpha_{1} \in W_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2} \in W_{2}$ to be equal to
$\alpha_{1}^{'}+\alpha_{2}^{'}$ where $\alpha_{1}^{'} \in W_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}^{'} \in W_{2}$.

Further,  $$\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}= \alpha_{1}^{'}+\alpha_{2}^{'} \implies   \alpha_{1}-\alpha_{1}^{'}= \alpha_{2}^{'}-\alpha_{2}$$ 
and since $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$  have only one element in common and here the two sides respectively the elements of $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ on left and right side , we can infer that both sides are further equal to $0$.

Therefore $\alpha_{1}=\alpha_{1}^{'}$ and $\alpha_{2}=\alpha_{2}^{'}$.

It's my method of solving the problem correct ? if there are any possible corrections, kindly mention.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your proof is correct and in this case we say that $V$ is a direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$ and we write
$$V=W_1\oplus W_2$$